# Django Rest Framework - Versioning docs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a versioned API using Django Rest Framework `NamespaceVersioning`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS':
        'rest_framework.versioning.NamespaceVersioning'
}
```

This works wonders and I can access all my v1 and v2 endpoints.

```
url(r'^v1/', include((router.urls, 'v1'), namespace='v1')),
url(r'^v2/', include((router.urls, 'v2'), namespace='v2')),
```

I am also using the Built-in API documentation as suggested in the [official docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/)

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title'))
]
```

My problem is that I'd like to have different docs for versions 1 and 2, since some serializers are different for each version.

If I do something like this:

```
url(r'^v1/docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title'))
url(r'^v2/docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title'))
```

I receive the following warning.

```
WARNINGS:
(urls.W005) URL namespace 'api-docs' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
```

Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: I would add it directly to the `router.url` so that it can be added along with other urls when you do `url(r'^v1/', include((router.urls, 'v1'), namespace='v1')),`

Comment: Could you please explain how to do so?

Comment: @Davlor show the contents of the file `router.urls`